# Should we add Redux as well when adding React in parts to an existing AngularJs app?

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, react-redux

This question is more of best practices than related to code, but I've been searching online for this for sometime without much progress.

We have an existing AngularJs (1.x) app and we are trying to add simple React components in it. Adding React is not the problem. I want to know if it makes sense to add Redux to this as well? I know that Redux is an app level state component, but since we are adding React in parts only, would using Redux be an unnecessary overkill in this case? I mention Redux only assuming that the complexity and number of React components might grow in the future. I wouldnt consider Redux if we we had to add only a handful of simple React components.

Here is an [excellent post](https://medium.com/@gethylgeorge/how-to-hook-reactjs-to-your-existing-angularjs-1-x-app-5ab1ac59c0c1) that adds React to an Angular app, but not Redux.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest reading [You might not need redux](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367) by Dan Abramov - the creator of redux.

The point of the article is to only use Redux if it solves a problem you are having. I would advise you to implement your react components and if you start to run into problems with state, investigate whether redux is a suitable solution for these specific problems.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I also suggest reading [You might not need redux](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367) as commented.

Going deeper in the problem, the important thing is to consider what is Redux for and why do I need it in the app. I would ask myself some questions:

- Where does you actual app state live in your angular app? Are you using scopes with models tied, centralised services with the data...? Are you planning to migrate that to a Redux store?
- Are you considering using Redux with Angular too, or only for the new React components? Is the data you are going to pass to you React components via Redux only used by React to render, or will it be shared with other Angular code?

  - If it's going to be shared, are you going to use Redux in your Angular code too? If not, will you have to sync you data manually between redux and your angular state? Personally, I don't like the idea of data replicated in a redux store and, for example, an angular service.
  - If you plan to use Redux with Angular, what about some Angular features like 2-way-binding, that can be in conflict with a Flux-like architecture? Will you try to force a flux-like design in your angular code too?
- Do those new React components share state? If not, any of those components' state is complicated enough to be hard to manage just lifting state up?

I ask all of this questions because I'm trying to isolate the problem and think about what I use Redux for: to be a single source of true in your data (for the entire app or complicated components).
Basically Redux is really helpful to keep state in sync between several parts of the app by design. However, if you don't need to keep components synced or, if other parts of your app (i.e. existing Angular code) are going to break that design and you will need to maintain the state sync (between Redux store and other parts of the app) by yourself, that can be a problem.

Also, regarding one of your concerns: 'assuming that the complexity and number of React components might grow in the future'. If you're thinking about complexity of the app state for react components, that can be a reason to think about Redux. If it's complexity just in terms of amount of components, I would consider it twice.

By my point of view, when you are using React for isolated views inside an app, lifting the state up can be a really valid solution. If the data and state get's complicated, you will 'feel' the need for a more elaborated solution.

Sorry for not having a solution, just hope to highlight a couple of questions that can help you to decide :)